# Java class naming with small letters

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions, class-design

I was wondering that can we start java class name with small letter for some special classes like any product name (facebook.java, apple.java, iPhone.java),

I know it is possible but will that cause any issues if these classes become part of any framework?

I have check some repositories on svn that are using classes that starts with small letters.

1. [apache](http://www.google.com/codesearch#2OQrpjVRYuU/trunk/src/java/org/apache/ecs/xhtml/code.java)
2. [openjdk](http://www.google.com/codesearch#V5msdoCsUcY/src/share/classes/com/sun/xml/internal/xsom/impl/parser/state/qualification.java)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will be cursed with inexplicable NullPointerExceptions for the rest of your life as punishment ;)

Comment: @mtariq, Hound Dog was being sarcastic.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot the markup for sarcasm. But if I scared you into doing it, that's great!

Comment: @mtariq - Actually, I knew a programmer once who used all-lower-case class names on a dare after a night out with the lads at the local tavern.  He used to wake up screaming that his bedroom was full of NullPointerExceptions and drop bears.  It got so that he gave up Java programming entirely.  Last I hear he was writing COBOL programs in a nunnery in Gundawindi.  You don't want this to happen to you.  (OK, I'm exaggerating ... but the drop bears are for real.)

Comment: @HoundDog ya got scared but now no more :)

Comment: @StephenC I would be surprised if anyone from Goondiwindi had seen a nun, let alone knew what COBOL was. They would, however, know what a drop bear is - those little buggers are always trying to cross the border into QLD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not cause any technical problems, as uppercase classnames are purely a convention (and not one used to carry technical meaning). However, it will irritate developers who have to work with these classes.

Comment: Even if it is possible, I would advise you not to do it. If I saw `facebook.someStaticMethod()`, I would instantly assume that facebook is an object, and that someStaticMethod() is an instance method which acts upon that object. There is IMO no reason not to call those classes Facebook, IPhone and Apple.

Answer (score 2):

It will not cause any **compile / runtime** issue, yet it will confuse people, as it violates the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

No this will not cause any issues. Naming conventions are just that, conventions. There are some guidelines as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java), but you don;t have to follow them.